# jQuery typing too quickly when autocompleting

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete

I am making a live search box and it seems that if I type normally and fast, it does not clear the html results in the div. Instead it puts the results for each keystroke in the div.

```
$('.searchbox').live('keydown', function(e){
  searchnow = $('.searchbox').val();
  $('#searchresultssmall').html(" ");
  setTimeout(function(){
 $('#searchresultssmall').show();
 fetch(400,"task=search&search="+searchnow);
   },1000);
 });
```

My fetch code is WAY too big, but is a piece of it

`case 400:
 if(obj.id)
     {
        $('#searchresultssmall').append('<div class="smallresult">'+obj.username+'</div>');
     }
 break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the previous timer. Optimized code would be:

```
var showResultsTimer = 0;
$('.searchbox').live('keydown', function(e){
    searchnow = this.value;
    var oResultPanel = $('#searchresultssmall');
    oResultPanel.html(" ");
    if (showResultsTimer)
        window.clearTimeout(showResultsTimer);
    showResultsTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        oResultPanel.show();
        fetch(400,"task=search&search="+searchnow);
    },1000);
});
```

This will show only the final value.

Edit: quick test reminded me that using `keydown` is wrong in your case, as you'll always miss the last character entered by the user. Use `keyup` instead.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/hhuX2/).

Comment: The `if (showResultsTimer)` portion is (IMO) redundant here, a `clearTimeout()` of an invalid timer is safe.  Also, this doesn't solve the problem of previous requests returning out of order :)

Comment: Good point, still prefer not to run `clearTimeout` when there's nothing  to clear - just personal habit. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is you're indiscriminately setting a timeout for searching 1 second after a keydown, this has a few issues:

- The user may have reversed and changed input
- Server requests are **not** guaranteed to return in order (some searches may be easier/faster than others)

What you should do is store that timer so you can clear it and not run any previously queued searches using [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout), like this:

```
var timerId;
$('.searchbox').live('keydown', function(e){
  searchnow = $('.searchbox').val();
  $('#searchresultssmall').html(" ");

  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#searchresultssmall').show();
    fetch(400,"task=search&search="+searchnow);
  },1000);
});
```

Also, you'll need to store the request inside your `fetch()` method (I can't be clear without more detail on this method) so you can call [`.abort()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on the previous request...so it can't come back *later* and replace the results of the latest thing the user actually typed in.  If that request *already* completed, well no harm there, it won't be messing with the results later down the line, it's already run its course and you've cleared it with the `.html(" ")` on this event handler.